# Not Getting any result in Powershell, Suspecting async issue

Tags: c#, powershell, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

Created a PowerShell Cmdlet command in C# and am trying to get the output after passing parameters. The function runs perfectly if I run it as a console application and I get the desired result,But when I am trying to invoke the method from PowerShell, I am not getting any records/results. I suspect there is a async issue which is causing the code to complete, but I am unable to figure it out.
During Debugging I get the status as RanToCompletion in ProcessRecord() Method. Will appreciate some advice on what's wrong in the code below.

```
 protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
       var changedFeed =  ProcessChangedRecords();
       changedFeed.Wait();
    }  
    
    private async Task ProcessChangedRecords()
    {
        DaysDuration = DaysDuration * -1;
        DateTime particularPointInTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(DaysDuration).ToUniversalTime();
        CosmosClient Client = new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint = https://test.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=ouJH1chKC5npTfK5y9NUEOA==;");
        if (DaysDuration == 0)
        {
            particularPointInTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        }            
       
        var database = Client.GetDatabase("databasename");
        var container = database.GetContainer("containername");
        var leaseContainer = database.GetContainer("leases");

        var cfp = container.GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<Document>(ChangeFeedProcessorName, ProcessChanges)
            .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
            .WithInstanceName(changeFeedInstanceName)
            .WithStartTime(particularPointInTime)
            .Build();
        await cfp.StartAsync();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await cfp.StopAsync();

    }


    public async Task ProcessChanges(IReadOnlyCollection<Document> docs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            WriteObject(doc, true);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        
    }
```

Just to be more precise, I am trying to use changefeed of CosmosDb and get the modified documents from a particular day. On running the above command, I can see the Lease instance getting created in lease container but there is no output in powershell window

Comment: Can you show the PowerShell code? Can you reproduce the issue with simpler code?

Comment: powershell command is straight forward get-recording -DaysDuration 7 -changeFeedInstanceName test1 -ChangeFeedProcessorName testprocessor

Comment: without powershell and running as simple console application it works fine

Comment: Where's the definition of `get-recording`?

Comment: Again, the simplest the repro, the more likely you'll get an answer.

Comment: here is the full code i have posted > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186934/not-able-to-call-c-function-for-cososdb-change-fee.html

Comment: here is powershell command - Get-ChangedRecording -DaysDuration 0 -changeFeedInstanceName Te0wa3w2a -ChangeFeedProcessorName TestProcess23w

Comment: If you notice, you didn't post the complete code here.

Comment: What happens if you remove `Task .Delay` from `ProcessChanges` and make it synchronous?

Why are you using `Task.Run`?

Why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: no change.. the above code runs fine as a console application and i just copy pasted in ProcessRecords() to call it from powershell.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you can achieve with a console application and not with the cmdlet and why do you think you need to create a cmdlet if a console application works.

It's also looking like you should be using the [pull model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-pull-model) instead of the push model.